# Getting an Unexpected Error in dotnet core Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my solution Explorer(Visual Studio) there are 5 projects

1. DigiIdentity(webapi)
2. Core(class library)
3. Data(class library)
4. Services(class library)
5. DigiPigmyApi(webapi)
6. DigiSyncApi(webapi)

I am getting following error while running the project(solution)

> Error CS1705  Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Actually I am not finding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0` package anywhere, can any one tell me the exact course of the error.

Comment: tried restarting visual studio?

Comment: It may be time to review and update your NuGet packages. Also look at the [References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project) of all Projects to see if anything there is marked as 'missing'.

Comment: I have restarted the vs but still not works

Comment: After closing visual studio. In your project folder delete the Bin folder. Open your project again and rebuild again. If you see same issue try restarting your machine.